# Windows 8 Setting an image on the login screen

Tags: windows-8.1, desktop-customization, login-screen

In Windows 8.1 when you log in there's the prelogin screen that has an image you can change, but then there's also the login (password entry) screen that as far as I can see is just a solid color.

How could I replace that with an actual picture? (ie, if I wanted a company logo to be displayed in the large space underneath the password entry box.

Answer (score 2):

You can't replace the logon background. This Windows 7 feature was removed in Windows 8. You can only change the background picture of the Lockscren (the useless thing before).

Comment: This is true. I don't like this either. I am using Windows 8.1 Pro with Update 1 and latest updates. I hope they change this in Windows 10. You know how you can make the Start screen transparent? The option "show my desktop background on Start" from Taskbar properties? I would love to see some transparency like that on the logon screen.

Comment: @sammyg this is not possible.

Comment: Tell me something I don't know. I was just saying it would be nice to have transparency on login screen; not saying it's possible.